# Reactjs does not render data in table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Obtaining data from firestore and trying to render in a table with reactJS I can not render it. Does anyone know if I have an error?

This is my code:

```
state = {
    items:[]
};

componentDidMount(){
    db.collection('items').get().then((snapShot) => {
        snapShot.docs.map( doc => {
           this.state.items.push({ id: doc.id, data: doc.data()});
        })
   }, error => {
       console.log(error)
   }); 
};
```

**Table**

```
render() {
    const { items, inputValue } = this.state;
    console.log(items)
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Table hover className="text-center">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>  
                    { items && items !== undefined ? items.map((item, key) => (
                        <tr><td>{item.data.item}</td></tr>
                     )): null }
                </tbody>
             </Table>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
```

Making a console.log of **this.state.items** I get the data like this:

```
0:{id: "1NDr66bsRosASM7qYCJb", data: {…}}
1:{id: "2k0DKLVBlPxZDIQt7KPx", data: {…}}
2:{id: "4cADNojHNXqkFcnl52jw", data: {…}}
```

And using map I can not access the data.

Can you help me, please? Thank you

Comment: `this.state.items.push` do not modify state object directly. Use `setState` method.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I do not know how I forgot that! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In componentDidMount() you have to set your state.

```
componentDidMount(){
    db.collection('items').get().then((snapShot) => {
       this.setState({
       items:snapShot.docs.map( doc => {
           return { id: doc.id, data: doc.data()}               
        });
       });
   }, error => {
       console.log(error)
   }); 
};
```